# Problem with parsing Json from the Supreme-Website in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

First of all this is my code:

```
import urllib.request, json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())


print(type(data['Shoes']))
```

Im trying to parse the Json, that i get from the Supreme Website with Python. Im trying to filter out the 'Shoes' Array. Printing out the whole 'data' works, but if im trying to filter out the 'Shoes' Array, I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-\PycharmProjects\-\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(type(data['Shoes']))
KeyError: 'Shoes'
```

The Json is to long to store it here, but you will find it under:

```
https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the json the `Shoes` are under products and categories:

```
data["products_and_categories"]["Shoes"]
```

this will get you the data you need

Comment: Did that :) Quick question, how do i access for example in the 'Shoes' Array the 'name'? Just adding ['name'] doesn't seems to work.

Comment: ah found out how:                                                              
data["products_and_categories"]["Shoes"][0]['name']

Comment: oh sorry, i thought i could gave it to both of you, i corrected that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
print(data['products_and_categories']['Shoes'])
```

Comment: Thanks to you aswell!